# Why won't this VHDL counter count

Tags: vhdl

I made this counter and I am sure it should work but my vector waveform files say otherwise. Y is only showing as a 4 bit number for starters which makes no sense

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity counter is generic (
    startnum : natural := 0;
    N : natural := 16
); port ( 
    --Inputs
    EN      : in std_logic;
    synchr  : in std_logic;
    asyncr  : in std_logic;
    dir     : in std_logic; -- 0 for count down 1 for count up.
    clk     : in std_logic;
    --Outputs
    Y       : out natural range startnum to n-1
);
end entity;

architecture counter_v1 of counter is
    signal cntconst :   integer;
begin
    process (dir)               --dir in sensitivity list as when this changes we want this process to run.
    begin
        if (dir = '0') then
            cntconst <= -1;                 --this will count down when added onto to the counter value
        end if;
        if (dir = '1') then
            cntconst <= 1;
        end if;
    end process;

    process (asyncr, clk)
        variable countvar : integer range startnum to n-1;--I tried to just use y but for some reason it won't allow that.
    begin
        if (en = '0') then
        else
            if (asyncr = '1') then
                countvar := 0;
            else
            --if (clk = '1') then
                --if (synchr = '1') then
                    --countvar := 0;
                --end if;
            --end if;
            end if;
            if (cntconst < n-1) then
                if (dir = '1') then
                    countvar := countvar + cntconst;
                end if;
            end if;
            if (cntconst > startnum) then
                if (dir = '0') then
                    countvar := countvar + cntconst;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
        y <= cntconst;
    end process;
end counter_v1;
```

Any help would be fantastic...I am at a total loss at this point
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a check for `rising_edge(clk)`, and your synchronous process can be simplified. Try:

```
architecture counter_v1 of counter is
    signal y_int: natural range y'range;
begin
    y <= y_int;

    process (asyncr, clk)
    begin
        if(asyncr = '1') then
            y_int < = 0;
        elsif(rising_edge(clk)) then
            if(en = '1') then
                if(dir = '1') then
                    if(y_int < y_int'high) then
                        y_int < = y_int + 1;
                    end if;
                else
                    if(y_int > y_int'low) then
                        y_int <= y_int - 1;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

I made a few changes to make the code act more like an FPGA logic cell:

- Removed synchronous reset: usually, you only need one type of reset
- Moved `en` check inside `rising_edge(clk)` check: `en` is normally a clock enable, so it shouldn't affect an asynchronous reset

Comment: That is much neater and easier to follow! For some reason it is giving me a compile error though Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Counter.vhd(39) near text "<"; expecting "(", or "'", or "."
I really don't understand why...any idea?

Comment: @Andeeh Oops! My code was trying to read from an `out` port. Updated the answer with the fix. I don't have a VHDL compiler with me, so hopefully, there aren't any more issues.

Answer (score 3):

You have defined Y as a natural range 0 to 15. That will fit nicely in 4 bits!

Answer (score 2):

Note that in the original code, the output `Y` is driven based on:

```
y <= cntconst;
```

where `cntconst` is derived by only the input `dir` and looks like an internal direction indication, and thus not the `countvar` that is supposed to be the counter state.  There will be a range violation since `cntconst` is integer range and can be -1, where the `Y` is only natural range.